# Express the volume of $Vol_{n-1}(M_a)$ with $c,\lambda$

Tags: calculus, integration, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

> Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to[0,\infty)$ smooth function and homogenous with $\lambda>0$($g(ax)=a^{\lambda}g(x)$) and $g(0)=0,\nabla g(x)\neq0,g(x)>0$ for all $x\neq0$,Setting $M_a=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:g(x)=a\}$ for all $a>0$.
> Assume that $Vol_{n-1}(M_1)=c$ Express the volume of $Vol_{n-1}(M_a)$ with $c,\lambda$

I've tried the following.
$Vol_{n-1}(M_a)=\int_{M_a}1dS=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{g^{-1}(a)}\frac{1}{\nabla g(x)}dx$ but couldn't figure how to connect this to $M_1$